# How to detect redundant piece of code containing array?

Tags: redundancy

The lecture for my Java class has this piece of code:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i=i+10){

if(i%10 == 0){

System.out.println(arr[i]);

}

}
```

If you start at 0 and then go 10, 20, etc. Why do you need the if condition? Naturally all of these numbers divide by 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant. The only way it could have an effect is when the array length is close to the Integer max value and you're causing overflows by adding 10, but then your code would loop infinitely anyway (or crash when accessing negative array values).

Answer (score 0):

To me the code in the if condition might have 2 reasones:

1. It is a way to monitor the progress of the function (although since the condition of the for loop is `i=i+10` instead of `i++`, it is less meaningful in this case). This is very normal when we are using some script to execute a task that is dealing with a lots of data (normally in single process, and take some time). By printing out the progress periodically we are able to know (or estimate) how many data has been read/wrtie, or how many times have the codes in the loop has been executed, in this case.
2. There might be more code added in the for loop, which might modify `i`. In this case, `i%10 == 0` will be meaningful.

In other words, without any more context it does seems like the `if` condition is redundant, in this case.

To answer the question of the title, here's what we usually do. First, have the code review done by someone else before you merge your branch. Having another fellow to review your codes are good practise as they could give you a fresh mind on correctness and code style. Second, if you find something that is suspecious but not sure (for example, the "redundant code" you think here), wrote unit tests to cover the part of code that you would like to change, make the changes and rerun the unit tests and see if you still get what is expected.

Personally I haven't heard of any tools that is able to detect "redundant code" as the example here, as "redundant" might not be "redundant" at all under different circumstances.